# How to give xml file path in XDocument.Load method in UWP C#

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

I have an XML file at Assets/Fonts/FontAwsome_version5.xml and I tried reading this file using the following method but it's giving an error - uri prefix is not recognized

`XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath); string filePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/FontAwsome_version5.xml";`

Comment: XML may have errors.  Try using VS to debug.  Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  A view will open.  Paste XML into view.  Error will be displayed in the Error List like compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

> How to give xml file path in XDocument.Load method in UWP C#

I'm afraid you can't load the file with UWP uri scheme for `System.Xml.Linq` namespace api, for the requirement, you could use Windows Storage Api to open the file as stream then call XDocument load stream method to access the file's xml content. For the testing the following code could work directly.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string filePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/Font.xml";
   var file =  await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(filePath));
    using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);

    }
  
}
```

Comment: thanks. It worked but I am facing problem to parse it. XML file is like this 

 <resources>
  <string name="fab fa-500px">\uf26e;</string>
  <string name="fas fa-abacus">\uf640;</string>
  <string name="far fa-abacus">\uf640;</string>
</resources>